# How IO monad makes concurrency easy to do in Scala?

Tags: scala, concurrency, io-monad

I watch this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=g_jP47HFpWA) and starts at 6min35s, it mentioned this graph:

[image]

saying that the IO Monad makes it easy to handle concurrency. I got confused on this: how does it work? How do the two `for comprehension` enable the concurrency (the computation of `d` and `f`)?

Comment: The answer is Monad composition. You will understand once you understand what monads are and how `for` comprehensions help you in composing monads. And I don't think this question can be truly answered without detailed explanation of monads and kleisli arrows, so it is pretty much outside the scope of what can be answered without writing a series of blogs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## No, it doesn't enable the concurrency

`for` comprehensions only help you omitting several parentheses and indents.

The code you referred, translate to `[flat]map` is strictly equivalent to:

```
async.boundedQueue[Stuff](100).flatMap{ a => 
  val d = computeB(a).flatMap{
    b => computeD(b).map{ result =>
      result
    }
  }

  val f = computeC(a).flatMap{ c =>
    computeE(c).flatMap{ e =>
      computeF(e).map{ result =>
        result
      }
    }
  }

  d.merge(f).map(g => g)
}
```

See, it only helps you omitting several parentheses and indents (joke)

## The concurrency is hidden in `flatMap` and `map`

Once you understand how `for` is translated to `flatMap` and `map`, you can implement your concurrency inside them.

As `map` takes a function as argument, it doesn't mean that the function is executed during execution of `map` function, you can defer the function to another thread or run it latter. This is how concurrency implemented.

Take `Promise` and `Future` as example:

````
val future: Future = ```some promise```
val r: Future = for (v <- future) yield doSomething(v)
// or
val r: Future = future.map(v => doSomething(v))
r.wait
````

The function `doSomething` is not executed during the execution of `Future.map` function, instead it is called when the `promise` commits.

## Conclusion

How to implement concurrency using `for` syntax suger:

1. `for` will convert into `flatMap` and `map` by scala compiler
2. Write you `flatMap` and `map`, where you will get a callback function from argument
3. Call the function you got whenever and wherever you like

## Further reading

The flow control feature of many languages share a same property, they are like delimited continuation `shift/reset`, where they capture the following execution upto a scope into an function.

JavaScript:

```
async function() {
  ...
  val yielded = await new Promise((resolve) => shift(resolve))
                                  // resolve will captured execution of following statements upto end of the function.
  ...captured
}
```

Haskell:

````
do {
  ...
  yielded_monad <- ```some monad``` -- shift function is >>= of the monad
  ...captured
}
````

Scala:

````
for {
  ...
  yielded_monad <- ```some monad``` // shift function is flatMap/map of the monad
  ...captured
} yield ...
````

next time you see a language feature which capture following execution into a function, you know you can implement flow control using the feature.

The difference between delimited continuation and call/cc is that call/cc capture the whole following execution of the program, but delimited continuation has a scope.